# Seeking software to allow users to draw spatial polygons

Tags: maps, gis, openstreetmap, google-maps

I am looking for a free (or low-cost) GIS-based software that allows users to draw spatial polygons using Google Earth as a background so they can draw a feature that is as precise as possible. A `download` button would be useful as well.

The polygons might be agricultural fields, parks within urban perimeters, construction sites etc. There would be around 3000 users drawing polygons (not necessarily at the same time but this would be the order of magnitude of the task).

This software would run on a Linux server but ultimately could be Windows as well. The user would be able to choose the name of the file to be saved in the server but the folder would be automatically determined by their username (or similar method that helps the administrator to easily identify and organize their files).

Is there such a tool available in the GIS ecosystem?

Answer (score 1):

On the assumption that you need a desktop solution, QGIS is free and open source. You can configure map layers, such as Openstreetmap, and capture polygons into a dataset, which could be a database if you really wanted (which I would recommend).

On the assumption you are wanting to standup a client-server web based application, given the simplicity of your requirements, but the scale of number of users, I would recommend not saving your polygons as individual files, but rather enable a database in the backend to save all records.
Postgres - Leaflet are able to be integrated. Leaflet is javascript libraries for mapping and has drawing tools and map layer tools available.
Further reading here on how to implement something similar for your needs.

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/266402/save-leaflet-drawn-features-with-attributes-to-postgis